# Can https content ever be cached at CDN datacentres?

Tags: ssl, https, cdn

I know that modern web browsers cache https content by default. But when you use, say, CloudFlare on your https webpage can it ever cache the css/jpg files for the client? I'm expecting the answer is no as its encrypted, but maybe the datacentre is intelligent and can establish its own connection as a client, cache, then serve as a proxy or something using its own certificates. Thanks

Comment: You mention CloudFlare. Did you consider searching on `CloudFlare SSL`? I found [this page](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) which describes *various* approaches that are available.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare is a content delivery network and not a simple load balancer. Because it is expected that they reduce the load on the original server they will cache also https traffic. This means that they will be a man in the middle and provide their own certificate for the site. For more information see their [SSL-FAQ](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ).